# Set table name dynamically, a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`database.yml` looks like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: database1
  username: root
  password: 

external:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: database2
  username: root
  password:
```

I have a class `ExternalDatabaseConnection`

```
class ExternalDatabaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(:external) #connect to external DB specified in database.yml
  attr_protected
end
```

I'm using `AR` to query on my external DB.

database2(external DB) is set dynamically from user end and I will not have any information about the tables and attributes.

database1(internal DB) which contains information about tables and some attributes.

---

So basically I have to handle things dynamically.

Works fine.

```
   ExternalDatabaseConnection.table_name = "set_table1" #dynamic
   ExternalDatabaseConnection.create(...) #creates a record.
```

This doesn't.

```
ExternalDatabaseConnection.table_name = "set_different_table" #dynamic
ExternalDatabaseConnection.create(...)
```

throws

```
unknown attribute: attribute_name
```

Both the things happen in loop, so every-time it works good for initial table set, for the second table, it throws an error.

Debugging:

[image]

Note:

```
ExternalDatabaseConnection.table_name = "payments"

ExternalDatabaseConnection.column_names
 => ["id", "customer_id", "patent_id", "amount", "currency", "date"]

ExternalDatabaseConnection.table_name = "patents"
 => "patents" 

2.0.0-p451 :006 > ExternalDatabaseConnection.column_names
 => ["id", "customer_id", "patent_id", "amount", "currency", "date"]

ExternalDatabaseConnection.all
ExternalDatabaseConnection Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `patents`.* FROM `patents` 
=> [#<ExternalDatabaseConnection id: 1, number: "1111", description: "https://www.google.co.in", registry_date: "2014-08-20", documnetdir: nil, currency: #<BigDecimal:a8f2adc,'0.1212E2',18(27)>>, #<ExternalDatabaseConnection id: 4, number: "1", description: "jhufgtrdfyuh", registry_date: nil, documnetdir: "", currency: #<BigDecimal:a8f2258,'0.0',9(18)>>, ....]
```

There is no change in attributes, may be this is causing a problem.

If any information is missing, comment up.

*ruby 2.0.0p451*

*Rails 3.2.17*

**edit1:**

Tries:

Before setting table name

1) `ExternalDatabaseConnection.table_name = nil` . 
2) `ExternalDatabaseConnection.clear_active_connections!` and `clear_all_connections!`
3) tried with `set_table_name :table1`

**edit2:**

`ClassName.column_names` is not getting changed even after setting different `table_name` for the `Class`

Comment: From the **Console image** which you posted,i can see you are giving `ExternalDatabaseConnection.create(number: "1234")` but there is no `number column` in the `specified table` which obviously gives you `unknown attribute: number`.

Comment: I think you meant to give `ExternalDatabaseConnection.create(amount: "1234")`

Comment: @Pavan check the note last point `ExternalDatabaseConnection.all` result.

Comment: What about the Image you posted.I don't see any column called `number` `ExternalDatabaseConnection.column_names output`.

Comment: Which specific rails version? 'Rails 3' covers over 30 versions

Comment: Rails has a bunch of reserved names for attributes - you'll probably find that `number` is likely to be one of them. What is the `number` column for exactly? Maybe you should consider re-naming it?

Comment: @RichPeck same with other attributes.

Comment: Will be able to jump into chat in a few minutes; I'd like to find out the result for this too (working on a similar project)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this following way. It may help

:set_table_name method is used to change the table name dynamically. You can set the table name and get the attributes name instead of columns name.

For payments table

> ExternalDatabaseConnection.set_table_name :payments
>
> ExternalDatabaseConnection.first.attribute_names

Then you have to reset the column information

> ExternalDatabaseConnection.reset_column_information

For patents:

> ExternalDatabaseConnection.set_table_name :patents
>
> ExternalDatabaseConnection.first.attribute_names

Comment: You have to reset the column information as well i updated the answer

Comment: Nice! Do you still need help on this `nithin`? I can jump into chat if so

Comment: @Hudson instead of `set_table_name`, `table_name =` is fine. As `set_table_name` runs query

Comment: Nice. I'll be using this when I get round to it later on!